# Retrieve geometry array from PostgreSQL by JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to use PostgreSQL JDBC to retrieve array elements of which type is geometry. But when I tried to use methods:

```
Route route=null;
String sql="Select * from route where route_id=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
try {
    pstmt = localConn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setInt(1,routeId);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
            Array points = rs.getArray("points");
            PGpoint[] pgPoints=points.getArray();
            ......
        }

}
```

error occured:

```
org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.getArrayImpl(long,int,Map) is not implemented.
```

So, are there any other methods that I can get elements in geometry array?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the SQL query?

Comment: yes,but i use PreparedStatement to build the sql:

Route route=null;
String sql="Select * from route where route_id=?";
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
try {
 pstmt = localConn.prepareStatement(sql);
 pstmt.setInt(1,routeId);
 ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
 if(rs.next()){
            Array points = rs.getArray("points");
            PGpoint[] pgPoints=points.getArray();
            ......
        }

}